# Meteor loginWIthGoogle problems

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have a page with a condition using a reactive variable that is initially false, but when you login, using facebook or google it changes to true, and the content of the page changes.

When i login using facebook everything goes well but when i login using google, the variable "isAuthenticated" doesn't changes to true, but if i navigate to another page, it appears as the user is logged in, so i thing what is happening is that when i do if(Meteor.userId()) authentication with google is not done yet, so it skips this step and doesnt changes the value of the variable. How can i wait till the authentication is completed? If i click again in the login with google it then enters the condition, it only doesnt work when the user is initially not logged in.

This is my login with google method:

```
 'click #google-login': function(event) { 
        event.preventDefault();
        Meteor.loginWithGoogle({}, function(err){
            if (err) {
                return swal({
                    title: "Google Login Failed",
                    timer: 1700,
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    type: "error"
                });                
                throw new Meteor.Error("Google login failed");
                Template.instance().authenticated.set(false);
            }
        });
            if(Meteor.userId()){
            //Enable idea submission
            Template.instance().authenticated.set(true);
            }
            //Update last login 
            Meteor.users.update( { _id: Meteor.userId() }, {$set: {"metadata.lastLoginAt": new Date()}});
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

First thing you can not set ReactiveVar in meteor.loginWithGoogle function try this

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){ 
  if (Meteor.userId()) {
  //Enable idea submission
  Template.instance().authenticated.set(true);
//Update last login 
  Meteor.users.update({
      _id: Meteor.userId()
  }, {
      $set: {
          "metadata.lastLoginAt": new Date()
      }
  });
 }
});

'click #google-login': function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var self = Template.instance();
Meteor.loginWithGoogle({}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return swal({
            title: "Google Login Failed",
            timer: 1700,
            showConfirmButton: false,
            type: "error"
        });
        throw new Meteor.Error("Google login failed");
        self.authenticated.set(false);
    } else {}
});

}
```